# How can I detect a failed login to Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to keep track of failed login attempts, for security auditing.

I see that there is a BeforeLogin trigger, but this only is called for successful logins.

I can detect a failed login via my website's login page, certainly, and call a Cloud function to record the failed login. But if a hacker were bypassing my website and sending login requests to my server directly, I would not find out about them.

Is there a trigger for failed logins, or for all logins?  Or some other way to do this?

Comment: This is a very interesting question indeed. Looking forward to seeing some answers over here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accountLockout` option.

For example:

```
accountLockout: {
    threshold: 3, //threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. Set it to an integer value greater than 0 and less than 1000
    duration: 5 // duration policy setting determines the number of minutes that a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becoming unlocked. Set it to a value greater than 0 and less than 100000.

  }
```

More info about this and other parse parameters can be found here:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#welcome-emails-and-email-verification

and here:

https://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/master/ParseServerOptions.html

Comment: I would like to execute a function when the login fails, not just lock the person out.

Comment: @leremjs I have no idea. I dont think parse server support this